# Victory in Yugioh by Unusual Means

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My first question is: Is it true that if your opponents obtains more than 5 back field cards (traps, etc) that they automatically lose?  I realize you cannot lay more than 5 cards in that area, but suppose your opponent already has 5 trap cards, then you use a trap card (for example Creature Swap) to swap one of your monsters with theirs.... except that the monster you give them has 2 traps attached to it already.  Now they have a total of 6 trap cards on their side.  What happens?  I've heard that they instantly loose and there is nothing they can do.  True?  Additionally, any other cool ideas on how to win using such "glitches" in the game.

Comment: It has been a long time since I played Yugioh but I believe in the situation you described the traps do not go to your opponents side. They stay on your side, taking up your trap/magic board area (I forget what it is called) they are just attached to his creature. This would not change the number of traps your opponent has on his side.

Comment: If they are attached to the creature.... then shouldn't they go with the monster to the other side?

Comment: I don't think so. Your opponent gets control of your monster but not your trap/magic card. It stays equipped to your old monster (now your opponents) but firmly under your control and on your side of the field.

Comment: I think the point is moot however. The official rules say the only "three" ways to win are by reducing your opponents life points to zero. If your opponent cant draw a card. Or if you have a special card affect that lets you win (such as Exodia).

Comment: A special card effect.... would include them getting more cards than they are allowed to have, no?

Comment: No. By a special card effect they mean a card that says you win if you meet certain criteria (Such as  Vennominaga the Deity of Poisonous Snakes). So unless a card exists that says "You win if you make your opponent play 6 traps" then you cannot win by this method.

Comment: I do not say this to discourage the question. I apologize if I came off that way. I am sure there are many cards out there that do have interesting effects that can let you win the game in interesting ways. I was simply trying to point out that I did not believe the given example would work.

Comment: Sure of course...  I'm still very interested in knowing about any other such glitches (perhaps there are none), but of course a comprehensive list of "instawins" would also fit here.

Comment: Calling these things 'glitches' seems like a misnomer to me.  This is a card game, and one in which the rules are easily malleable by the designers; any 'non-standard' win conditions are there because they were explicitly put there by the designers, not because they happen to be some bizarre accident of the rules.

Comment: Hence put in quotation marks..... Either contribute or don't, but don't make a fuss about semantics

Comment: @Squirtle I think Steven may be trying to gently hint that your question isn't very well formulated. Half of your question is a rules question ("does this odd game condition cause you to win, even though it's not in the rules?") and the other half is a vague request for nonstandard win conditions. "What are all the cards which say 'you win the Duel' on them?" is a pretty broad question, not the sort of thing people tend to go for. And "when do you win the game?" is a fair (if basic) rules question, but you didn't ask it either.

Comment: I would just like to point out that cards you control can be equipped or otherwise "attached" (not an official term) to monsters your opponent controls; [Cursed Armaments](https://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cursed_Armaments) is a card that equips itself to your opponent's monsters, for example, and [Fiendish Chain](https://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Fiendish_Chain) is typically used to target your opponent's monsters.  In neither of these cases does your opponent gain control of the S/T card (rather, it remains in your control, so you pay the unmentioned cost of "one occupied S/T zone" to maintain it).

Comment: Also, special effects that make you win are effects that explicitly say either that you win, or that your opponent loses.

Answer (score 8):

**No, you do not win the game if your opponent somehow controls 6 Trap cards.** There are only three ways to win a game of [Yu-gi-oh (page 26 or 30 in pdf)](http://www.yugioh-card.com/uk/rulebook/3R03803_-_SD21_YGO_RuleBook_EN.pdf):

> **Winning a Duel**
>
> Each player starts a Duel with 8000 Life Points. You win a Duel if: you reduce your opponent's Life Points to 0; if your opponent is unable to draw a card; or if a card's special effect says you win. [...]

There are no "glitches", or other ways of winning a game.

Comment: Except in tournament play. You can win a game or duel via tournament penalty as applied by a tournament official like a judge.

Comment: You can also win in a tournament if the round time is over and end-of-round procedures determine you as the winner. Note that these are NOT official (per the rules) "win conditions", so you are **not** allowed to aim your play towards these situations. If you intentionally play in a way that makes you win by having your opponent receive a Game or Match Loss or drag the game to overtime on purpose in order to win by the timeout procedures, you risk being disqualified from the tournament for Cheating (which is a form of Unsporting Conduct)!

Answer (score 2):

As [user1873 pointed out](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/12505/), this isn't a way your opponent can be defeated. Furthermore, you cannot control more than five non-Field Spell or Trap cards. Spells and Traps on your side of the field are under your control, even if they are equipped to cards your opponent controls.

You should read or re-read the rule book. If you have already read it, it appears you have some significant misunderstandings.